# Button (In silverlight) does not have Click property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight-4.0

I need my silverlight button to call a specific method, but my button doesn't have any click property.  The Intellisense shows "clickmode" but no "click"

I'm definitely using the System.Windows.Controls.Button control

Here's my code for the xaml file

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Telerik_Windows_Controls="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Charting" x:Class="..."
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

        <Telerik_Windows_Controls:RadChart Name="radChart" Content="RadChart" Margin="78,47,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"/>


    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WPF button has an "OnClick" event, or a "Command" property. You may find this link useful: [WPF Commanding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight's `Button` does have an event called `Click`, defined in `ButtonBase`, see the [MSDN API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). So you might write XAML like:

```
 <Button Content="Button" ... Click="My_Event_Handler"/>
```

However, have a look at Commanding as referenced by the other answer for the "nice" way to do things ([Button's Command property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)).